# Cakephp 2.1 Image Upload Plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am looking for Plugins to upload content - mainly images. I found a couple of plugins which are for 1.3 but not none for 2.1

could you please share a few plugins for 2.1

Comment: you could try customizing the existing 1.3 ones if you dont find for 2.1

Comment: Hey, is this a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275459/cakephp-image-file-uploader-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried meio upload? It is compatible with cake 2.x?

https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload

Answer (score 2):

A nice one i just found:

- https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin

i have not tested it much, but it seems to work great, you even can define additional image sizes to be created automaticalliy.

Answer (score 1):

You could customize 1.3 version plugin for 2.1 or use something like this: [CakePHP File Upload](https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload)

Answer (score 1):

Although the others are nice, I found this one a lot more easy to use than the others check it out :

https://github.com/malikov/cakephp2.0-image-upload

Answer (score 0):

I use wrapper for cakephp imagine Library:

https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin

Answer (score 0):

[Upload](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) plugin is available now at Github