# CakePHP Image/File Uploader Plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am looking for a decent working Image/File uploader for CakePHP 2.1.

I am using Meio Uploader and it gives me weird errors all the time -> Invalid File type even though i have configured to upload a JPG file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Cake PHP media plugin](https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin) which is a fork for Cake 2.0 of popular [Cake media plugin](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/) by David Persson.

I am using the original plugin on a 1.3 installation and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax File Upload using jQuery and CakePHP Media Plugin

http://pixelcone.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-using-jquery-and-cakephp-media-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Use can [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), its very easy to implement with CakePHP 2.1.